# How do I collect entered data from child components created by ngFor in parent component?

Tags: angular

I have a component that asks 1 question and will return 1 answer to parent component.

the problem is: 
I don't know how do I access data passed from child component.

here is my codes:

child.component.html:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Question {{this.row}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input  matInput
              required
              [placeholder]="placeholder"
              autocomplete="off"
              [(ngModel)]="value">
    </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
 </mat-card>
```

child.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  value: string;
  @Input() row: number;
  @Input() placeholder: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

parent.component.html:

```
<p>
  Questions!
</p>
<app-child  *ngFor="let question of questions"
            [placeholder]="question.question"
            [row]="question.row">
</app-child>
```

parent.component.ts:

```
import { ChildComponent } from './../child/child.component';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  parentvalue: string;
  value: string;
  parentData: string;
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: false}) childReference: ChildComponent;


  questions: any[] = [
    {row: 1, question: 'What`s your name?' },
    {row: 2, question: 'How old are you?' },
    {row: 3, question: 'where did you born?' },
    {row: 4, question: 'What`s your father`s name?' },
    {row: 5, question: 'Who is your childhood hero?' },
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  viewchildmethod() {
    this.parentvalue = this.childReference.value;
  }
}
```

How do I collect answers separately?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways.

**1. Manipulation of the object**

But one of the simpliest way here is to pass the whole object to child, not only the object's primitive properties. You could use mutability of arrays and objects...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mptuxa-6jgz7a

Doing so, you have the reference for the value.

**2. Using Event Emitter:**

Add EventEmitter to your child.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mptuxa-nut3ut

**3. Using services to pass changed values**

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

**-- But these question can be answered easily if you read the official examples (https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview). --**

Comment: thank you so much. I think this will work properly. But I'm not intended to manipulate Questions object. Actually I want to access each component created by *ngFor just with it's data passing mechanism. do you have any other offers?